# AngularJS : "Deep" application vs. "wide" application? AKA many components/directives vs. many controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Which is better: to split up an application into many different directives/components or into many different controllers?

Splitting up the application into many different directives/components creates a **"deep" application**.  There are more files in a "deep" application, but is inherently more modular.  Advantages: working in a team environment, there is less chance that two people's efforts will bump into each other (causing painful merges).  It's easy to share code between projects.  Disadvantages: if you want to look into an issue, you have to follow a chain of code to get to where you need to be.  Example: there is an issue with a radio directive.  You must first go to the template, figure out which component the radio directive is probably in, look in there to see the directive definition, then finally go to the directive file.

*Extreme example*: imagine a form with 10 questions.  Each question is a directive.  The form itself is a component.  The form is loaded into a visual section, which the section is a component.  The various sections that make up the page are loaded into the template.  If you were new to the project, and there was a problem with form question 7, you must "dig" from the template down to find the directive.

Splitting up the application into many different controllers creates a **"wide" application**.  There are less files in a "wide" application, but each controller is in charge of one aspect of the template.  Advantages: you can easily look in the template and find everything defined.  Each area of responsibility is taken over by a controller.  Disadvantages: in a team environment, multiple people will be working in the same file.  Sharing code with projects is more involved.

*Extreme example*: imagine a form with 10 questions.  Each question has a controller (for validation).  The form has a controller (to check when all questions are valid).  The form resides in a section, which has a controller.  If you were new to the project, and there was a problem with form question 7, you would have to find the controller that controls.

So which do you think is better and why?  A "deep" application or a "wide" application?

Vocabulary (as I understand it, and please feel free to correct me)

- Directive: comprised of an HTML template and a javascript directive file.  You put your DOM manipulation logic in here, or any other complicated logic.  Example: a drop-down, a datepicker, anything from jQuery UI.
- Component: a reusable piece of code meant to abstract commonalities.  You can do this visually; imagine a comic book page.  There are many frames separated by gutters.  Each frame is a component, meant to hold a piece of art.
- Template: brings together all partials, components, and directives.  The template will be rendered by angular into the view.
- Partial: a piece of static HTML that is meant to be pulled into a template.
- View: the compiled version of the template.  The view doesn't exist until angular compiles it.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for "deep" variant.  Code reuse is a very important thing.

> You must first go to the template, figure out which component the
>   radio directive is probably in

Why? Just look at name of the directive and open corresponding file. Create predictable folder structure when you can find any necessary file by name of directive or controller or service.

For example, your directive named `acme-radio` where `acme` is your vendor-prefix, so file should be in folder `vendor/acme/directives/radio.js`.
Other directive is exclusive for some app and named `acme-appName-radio` - file should be in `appName/directives/radio.js`.
It's just rough example.

Comment: Broad question, but could you explain more about predictable folder structures?

I am using angular-seed as my folder-structure at the moment.

Comment: @AndrewAllbright very "holywar"-able question :) Here is my opinion in a long discussion thread in Yeoman repository: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/109#issuecomment-22461746

Comment: Awesome read so far.  Too bad there isn't a yeoman generator for ngBoilerplate...(yet)!

I like the idea of organizing code into functional areas.  Unfortunately, there is legacy code that I would have to convert into this new directory structure, which entails a lot of work.  That said, I think it's worth doing in the long run.

I appreciate your help and will continue reading through the material you provided :)